# How to return related field instead of reference number in a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

I have a generic MySQL statement used for many tables that just retrieves all data for a single table:

```
$table = "profiles";//set static for example
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$table`");
```

I would like the results to show the text from `position` in place of `job_id`.
How do I do this if I still want my query to remain generic and there could be multiple fields that are references to other tables where I would want the related text not the id?

```
mysql> show columns from profiles;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| staff_id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| job_id      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| name        | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> show columns from job_positions
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| job_id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| position    | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Is there some kind of relationship I can set on these fields and then issue a command with the query to return the related text instead of the id's?

Comment: Sounds like you want a **Good PHP ORM Library**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view:

```
create or replace view info as
select p.job_id as job_id, p.name as name, j.position as position
from profile as p, job_position as j where p.job_id=j.job_id
```

Then you can still using your query

```
$table = "info";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$table`");
```

Comment: This looks promising however what about tables with no view? Is there a way to check for a view on a table and if so run the query where $table = $tablename."_view" otherwise $table = $tablename?

Comment: The point of the generic mysql statement is that $table is automatically assigned from the user action e.g. they click the profile button so it assigns 'profile' as the $table. I can't change it to 'people_view' as this will break other things in the program. Therefore I would need to change it right before running the SQL. hence if I called the view I created 'profile_view' I could use $table.'_view' however the other queries using this generic statement will fail as there is no view created for them and therefore no $table.'_view'